# Weird rendering of the album-art-image in custom receiver

Tags: google-cast

I've developed a custom receiver which works very nicely, however the rendering of the graphic on the album art image looks weird. I've also tried the "styled media receiver", just to be sure that I haven't screwed anything up - same result.

Anyone else seen this (check the image below)? The channel logo is a transparent PNG.

[Screenshot of bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs9b9.png)

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems to be happening in case the album art contains a transparent layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the cssText property - removing this, fixes the rendering issue:

```
var fixDoubleLogoBug = function(){
    try {
        document.querySelector("#player")
        .shadowRoot
        .querySelector("#castMetadataImage").style.cssText = "";
    }catch(e){
        console.warn("Could not remove logo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let shadowRootElement = document.querySelector( 'cast-media-player' ).shadowRoot;
let style = document.createElement( 'style' );
style.innerHTML = '#castMetadataImage { background-image: none !important; }';
shadowRootElement.appendChild( style )
```

Run this right after the player has been initizied and it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code. It's difficult to know without any code to review. Did you follow the official guide on https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/customize_ui for receivers applications? Also you need to check your sender application.

Comment: I used the example from codelabs (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-receiver). It seems the issue appears when using a transparant metadata image. An extra larger version the image is rendered on top.

Comment: That's my conclusion as well - transparent images causes the rendering to fail and show "double" images.

Comment: By the way, it's difficult to share any code when the entire CAF framework is hosted and maintained by Google. I can share the PNG if that helps, but doubt it.